# Clicking on external link opens a tab in wrong Chrome window

Tags: macos, google-chrome

### The setup

- 2 monitors are connected to my Mac Pro 4.1 running El Capitan 10.11.4
- Monitor 1 is a desktop monitor
- Monitor 2 is a TV
- My default browser is set to Chrome (Version 46.0.2490.71 (64-bit))

---

### How I use the computer

I usually have multiple Chrome windows opened at the same time. At least a window for each monitor, but sometimes more.
When I'm watching movies/tv-shows and other entertainment stuff i use the tv and use the Chrome-window on the tv for stuff related to entertainment.
The desktop monitor is used for school/work stuff and researching different things, so i use the Chrome window there for that kind of stuff.

### Problem scenario

Now lets say I have a Powerpoint slideshow or an email with a link in on the desktop monitor, and I click  that link, then a new tab would sometimes be created in the wrong Chrome window on the tv, even though i just used the desktop monitor Chrome window.

### How I normally work around the problem (in a less than optimal way)

I normally resolve it by right-clicking the Chrome Dock-icon -> Settings -> "assign to Desktop on monitor *x*", which will move all the Chrome windows to monitor *x*. But it's becoming a bit annying because i would have to setup the window size everytime i do this.

So I'm wondering if someone in here knows of a better solution to open windows in the "current" Chrome window.

Comment: Update Chrome to v50 and try disabling any Chrome flags you've turned on.

Comment: Yeah, maybe a good idea. I'll try your suggestion, and see if it helps anything. Will see if I keep having problems for the next couple of days, since i haven't really found out how the Chrome window selection pattern works. Thanks for your suggestion.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Links are opened in the newest window, so the solution would be to open your media Window and move it to the TV first, then open another window for other things on your main display.

EDIT: When it comes to preference, I too wish there was a way to change this behavior. Opening in the most recently focused window makes sense to me.

Comment: Yes, I think that was how it should work. It would feel more right if it worked this way. I guess this also goes for other OS X applications then?

Comment: This doesn't seems to work for me. macOS 10.12.1 & Chrome 54.0.2840.98. Anyone got another suggestion?

Comment: This doesn't work for me in current Chrome either. If I open a new window with Cmd-N and open a few tabs there, the next time I click an external link it still opens a tab in an older window on the other monitor instead.